# Django Order by on 'related_name' after filtering last record

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

This is how the sample model looks like

**models.py**

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=16)

class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, related_name="get_bars")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**Sample Data**

> hello_foo

[image: hello_foo]

> hello_bar

[image: hello_bar]

**Objective**:

Find all `foos` sorted by its `timestamp` in the last connected `bar` record. (`foo` is connected to `bar` with one to many relationship)

**What I tried**

I know how to filter `foo` based on `bar`

```
foos = hello.models.Foo.objects.filter(get_bars__name="foo1-bar1")
```

I can also order `foo` based on `bar` name

```
foos = hello.models.Foo.objects.order_by("-get_bars__name")
```

**But how do I use this to perform order by on last bar record for a foo?**

**Sample plain SQL I would write it like this:**

```
select foo.name, bar.last_ts
from hello_foo as foo 
    inner join 
    (select foo_id, max(timestamp) as last_ts from hello_bar group by foo_id) as bar
    on foo.id = bar.foo_id
order by bar.last_ts desc
```

---

I am using django 1.11 and python3

Comment: Did you try hello_bar.get_bars.all(). For further reference https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects based on django 1.11

Comment: I don't want all `bar`, I want to sort `foo` based on last `bar` record

Comment: hello_bar.objects.order_by(-timestamp).values(foo__id)

Comment: No I just want last `timestamp` of multiple `bar` records. foo is one to many with bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can annotate the [Max](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/) of `timestamp` with the queryset and order by that.
So, try like this:

```
from django.db.models import Max

Foo.objects.annotate(max_t = Max('get_bars__timestamp')).order_by('max_t')
```